# Paste does not start at last row

Tags: count, copy, row, paste

I got the following macro that copy sheet1 A1:A6 to Sheet2 transpose but copy the same row with the count in column G of sheet 1. The macro must paste one paste under the other on sheet 2 but keeps on copying other the same lines.

Sub CountRows()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim startCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim rowCount As Long

```
' Set the starting cell
Set startCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G4")

' Find the last row in column G
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    
' Calculate the row count
rowCount = lastRow - startCell.Row + 1

' Display the result
MsgBox "Number of rows: " & rowCount

' Copy the range "A1:A6"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6").Copy

' Start looping through the rows
For i = 1 To rowCount
    ' Paste the value in each row of a specific column (e.g., column A)
                   
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Clear the clipboard
```

End Sub

If someone can help